# RoleInterface throws "call on a non-object" error

Tags: symfony

I'm working over Symfony 2.0.16

I have in my UserProvider the method getRoles

```
public function getRoles()
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $rol
     */
    return $this->rol->toArray();
}
```

and my Rol entity has the role interface

```
class Rol implements \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface
//...
public function getRole()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
```

but when I try to login I get the following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getRole() on a non-object in C:\Users\julian\Code\parqueadero\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DataCollector\SecurityDataCollector.php on line 57

Reading the class SecurityDataCollector, the error is thrown by a Closure

```
array_map(function ($role){ return $role->getRole();}, $token->getRoles()
```

Now I change this to

```
array_map(function ($role){ var_dump($role); return $role->getRole();}, $token->getRoles()
```

To my surprise, `$role` is a object Rol but **I can't understand why I get the error.**

Comment: array_map calls this function for all the elements returned by getTokens. Are you sure all of them are Rol objects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution the problem is a **bug in PHP 5.4** (the php i'm using) **serialize method** the github user [yoannch](https://github.com/yoannch) proposed this [solution](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3691#issuecomment-5041109), is overwrite the `serialize/unserialize` methods using `json_encode/json_decode` methods

```
class User implements \Serializable

//...

/**
 * Serializes the content of the current User object
 * @return string
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return \json_encode(
            array($this->username, $this->password, $this->salt,
                    $this->rol, $this->id));
}

/**
 * Unserializes the given string in the current User object
 * @param serialized
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list($this->username, $this->password, $this->salt,
                    $this->rol, $this->id) = \json_decode(
            $serialized);
}
```

only need change the correct name properties

Comment: Thanks for saving me another day searching what the hell is wrong with my code. I'll just revert to 5.3.x. I've had tons of problems because of 5.4.

Comment: more info in the "official issue": https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3691

Comment: Thks for the reference :) but as Ztere0 said, there's an official solution on Github

Comment: @YoannCh that was the solution i've found ^_^

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, but looks like roles are not being serialized do you know what can be wrong ?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem (Windows, PHP 5.4.5), updated to 5.4.7 and it still did not work. Nevertheless, I came up with a workaround that needs less maintenance (when overwriting the serialization functions as described in the article you mentioned, you'll have to keep them up to date when adding/removing fields). So far it works for me, I hope there are no other problems resulting from the workaround I might have forgotten. Just alter the User's `getRoles()` function like that:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = array();
    foreach ($this->userRoles as $role) {
        $roles[] = $role->getRole();
    }

    return $roles;
}
```

Note that `$role->getRole()` returns the role name as a String (e.g. `ROLE_ADMIN`).

Comment: Cool workaround. I have tested it and it works! Thank you @MichaelB

Comment: Thanks. That was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 6):

solution of this problem is very simple.
All problems associated with circular references at yours `User` and `Role` objects.
So you have not to serialize `User::$roles` and `Role::$users` fields.

Look at `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken::__construct()` and `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken::serialize()`.

How you can see, Symfony take your user's roles by invoking `UserInterface::getRoles()` before serialization. And serialize `User` and `Roles` separately.

You have to implement `\Serializable` interface in `User` and `Role` entities.

### Example:

```php
/**
 * Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $username
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string $salt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var string $password
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var boolean $isActive
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * User's roles. (Owning Side)
     * 
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $roles;

    // .....

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        /*
         * ! Don't serialize $roles field !
         */
        return \serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->email,
            $this->salt,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->email,
            $this->salt,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive
        ) = \unserialize($serialized);
    }

}
```

```php
/**
 * Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Role
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * 
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $role
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * Users in group (Inverse Side)
     * 
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    // .....    

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        /*
         * ! Don't serialize $users field !
         */
        return \serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->role
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->role
        ) = \unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

And all will be serialized/unserialized correctly.

See discus at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3691

See also:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html#serializing-entity-into-the-session

Comment: For some reason this is not working with me. Symfony2.1.3 & php 5.4.9. I get successfully login but then I get an exception in the logs `[2012-12-17 17:19:26] security.INFO: Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point (A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.) [] []` and I'm pointed back to the login page.

Comment: Look for errors in your code. Or show me the code of `security.yml` and the user model. I'll try to help.

Comment: I believe that this solution is correct.
See discus on the GitHub: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3691#issuecomment-9831914