# Fatal error: Call to a member function getRoles() on a non-object

Tags: php, zend-framework

While trying to setup a zend framework based application. i am getting this error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getRoles() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\issues-master\application\modules\default\services\Acl.php on line 47

I went through the code and dont see anything wrong. below is the code,

```
/**
 * _setupRoles 
 * 
 * @return void
 */
protected function _setupRoles()
{
    $this->_roles = $this->_roleService->getAllRoles();
    foreach ($this->_roles as $i) {
        $this->_acl->addRole($i);
    }
    $currentRoles = Zend_Registry::get('Default_DiContainer')->getUserService()
        ->getIdentity()->getRoles();

    $this->_acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'), $currentRoles);
}
```

please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, i have called a method using a non object. in my case,

```
Zend_Registry::get('Default_DiContainer')->getUserService()
        ->getIdentity()
```

this was having null as a value so i am unable to call getRoles();

another answer can be found here : [RoleInterface throws "call on a non-object" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251825/roleinterface-dont-working-properly)