# symfony2 - add roles to an user that implements UserInterface

Tags: symfony, user-interface, roles

I have an Entity called User that implements UserInterface, so it has the method getRoles():

> function getRoles() {
>       return array('ROLE_CLIENT'); }

Is it possible, once the user has been created, to add another role to that user?

Answer (score 0):

Use `__construct` method for adding user role by default

```
// Your user entity
class User {

    public function __constuct() {
        $this->roles = array(
            'ROLE_CLIENT', // or other roles
        );
    }

}
```

or in action of controller where you create new user add any roles to them.

Comment: Hi, my class is: class User implements UserInterface{... function getRoles() { return array('ROLE_CLIENT'); ...}. So, in this function is where I am specifying the role. There is no field in my class that stores the roles. However, the role is saved because of the implementation of UserInterface. My question is... how can I add more roles to an user that has already been created.

Comment: To add more roles to user you can simply add them to array as `array("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_SUBSCRIBER")`. But better store the roles in DB like realize in [Managing Roles in the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database)

Comment: I have tried to use the RoleInterface as you have told me, but I am using php 5.4 and it is causing me a problem when I try to log in when there are users already created in the db (same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251825/roleinterface-dont-working-properly). I would really like to do it like this, but I think there is no solution... So, how can I add roles from the Controller to an user that has already been created?