# Role entities in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

I'm trying to use Doctrine to persist the role of my users.

The entities are up and running but when I try to login I have this error :

> FatalErrorException in RoleHierarchy.php line 43: Error: Call to a
>   member function getRole() on string

I tried to see what was this "string" and it is :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
```

Here is my Role entity :

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* Class Role
* @package AppBundle\Entity
*
* @ORM\Entity()
* @ORM\Table("fxm_role")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/
class Role implements RoleInterface
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column( type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $role
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $role;

/**
 * @var string $name
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var \DateTime $created
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $created;

/**
 * @var \DateTime $updated
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $updated;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function updatedTimestamps()
{
    $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime('now'));

    if ($this->getCreated() == null) {
        $this->setCreated(new \DateTime('now'));
    }
}

/**
 * Get role
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRole()
{
    return $this->role;
}
```

For the user here is the used part for the roles

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $roles
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $roles;

/**
 * Returns the roles granted to the user.
 *
 * <code>
 * public function getRoles()
 * {
 *     return array('ROLE_USER');
 * }
 * </code>
 *
 * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
 * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
 * is created.
 *
 * @return Role[] The user roles
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->toArray();
}
```

I really don't know what is the problem, but because I don't even have the profiler bar, the entity are not even loaded for some reason.

The role hierarchy is nothing complicated either :

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_BACKOFFICE: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_BACKOFFICE
```

If anyone know how to fix this issue it would be nice I've been stuck on this for a while now (And there is not really a lot of documentation fo the Role as an entity).

UPDATE : For some weird reason it worked once giving me the Role Array

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(AppBundle\Entity\Role)[437]
      private 'id' => int 1
      private 'role' => string 'ROLE_BACKOFFICE' (length=15)
      private 'name' => string 'Back Office' (length=11)
      protected 'created' => 
        object(DateTime)[370]
          public 'date' => string '2015-07-13 11:43:31.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
      protected 'updated' => 
        object(DateTime)[365]
          public 'date' => string '2015-07-13 11:43:31.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
```

But failed after I refreshed the page. So there is a weird inconsistency going on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and some tests, it looks like this issue relate to the one with **PHP 5.4** even if I'm on **PHP 5.6** ([RoleInterface throws "call on a non-object" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251825/roleinterface-throws-call-on-a-non-object-error))

I tried changing the serialization process with the **JSON** function and the issue is now gone. So for now `serialize` and `unserialize` are creating an issue but I don't know why.